# Selenium suites is not running on Chrome and running on FF?

Tags: selenium

***Case 1:***

When using:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>java -jar C:\selenium\selenium-2.25.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -htmlSuite "*googlechrome" https://accounts.google.com/ "C:\selenium\Ide\test_suite.htm" "C:\selenium\Ide\results.htm"
```

Getting Exception:

> HTML suite exception seen: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Google Chrome could not be found in the
>   path! Please add the directory containing ''chrome.exe' or
>   'google-chrome' or 'Google Chrome'' to your PATH environment
>   avariable, or explicitly specify a path to Google Chrome like this:
>   *googlechrome c:\blah\chrome.exe

***Case 2***

**So Changed**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>java -jar C:\selenium\selenium-2.25.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -htmlSuite "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://accounts.google.com/ "C:\selenium\Ide\test_suite.htm" "C:\selenium\Ide\results.htm"

Getting:

HTML suite exception seen:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Browser not supported: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
(Did you forget to add a *?)

Supported browsers include:
  *firefox
  *mock
  *firefoxproxy
  *pifirefox
  *chrome
  *iexploreproxy
  *iexplore
  *firefox3
  *safariproxy
  *googlechrome
  *konqueror
  *firefox2
  *safari
  *piiexplore
  *firefoxchrome
  *opera
  *webdriver
  *iehta
  *custom

```
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.BrowserLauncherFactory.browserNotSupported(BrowserLauncherFactory.java:151)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.BrowserLauncherFactory.getBrowserLauncher(BrowserLauncherFactory.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.getBrowserLauncher(HTMLLauncher.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.runHtmlSuite(SeleniumServer.java:612)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:286)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:244)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:54)
```

23:23:19.194 INFO - Shutting down...

***Case 3***

**So Changed again with browser as *chrome**

it should run on chrome but it is running on Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use *googlechrome to run on Chrome browser.
And add the directory containing 'chrome.exe' or 'google-chrome' to your PATH environment.
Note - If you just say *chrome it will invoke Firefox Chrome.

It should also work by updating  "*googlechrome" argument as - 
 "*googlechrome C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Comment: Perfect!! So my case 2 is slightly correct but i did not include *googlechrome infront of path..